# Session parameter is aways null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, null

I am trying to pass a string from one servlet to another but I always get a null value in the second servlet. I've banged my head against this one for almost 2 weeks to no avail and I've run out of ideas. I've read all the similar question posted on here and I still get a null value.

This is the first servlet

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    try 
    {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
        int userId = DBConnect.getIdByName(name);
        int lobbyId = DBConnect.insertInLobby(userId);
        request.setAttribute("lobbyId", lobbyId);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("PlatformPairsLobby.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } 
    catch (ServletException | IOException e) 
    {
        logger.error("Error " + e);
    }
}
```

This is the second servlet with the name string that always is null.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
    int id = DBConnect.getIdByName(name);
    request.setAttribute("id", id);
    String lobbyId = request.getParameter("lobbyId");
    request.setAttribute("lobbyId", lobbyId);
    response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
    try 
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("PairsJnlp.jsp").include(request, response);
    } 
    catch (ServletException | IOException e)
    {
        logger.error("Error " + e);
    }
}
```

To access the second servlet, I use a button in this JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.awt.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="database.DBConnect"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<html>
<head>
<%  
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) 
request.getAttribute("lobbyList");
Integer lobbyId = (Integer) request.getAttribute("lobbyId");
%>

------------------

window.location.href = 
"http://192.168.100.154:8080/GamePlatformCore/SecondServlet?lobbyId=<%=lobbyId%>";
```

The name is set in a different servlet.

```
request.setAttribute("verificare", verificare);
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("name", name);

if(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("userMessages")==null)
{
    request.getServletContext().setAttribute("userMessages",new ArrayList<String>());       
}

request.getRequestDispatcher(WELCOME_PAGE).forward(request, response);
```

Comment: You should really separate out the Java and the Display by putting the Java into Servlets and the Display into JSP (MVC paradigm)

Comment: I am confused, in your Servlet1 you call `PlatformPairsLobby.jsp` - are you saying that you have a doGet method in the JSP?

Comment: I don't see that you put anything in the Session.  Try  `session.setAttribute("lobbyId", lobbyId);`

Comment: PlatformPairsLobby.jsp is the jsp posted last. I tried session.setAttribute("name", name); in the first servlet and still did not work

Comment: Are you sure that the *`Session`* is null? The call shown is never allowed to return null. (Also, you almost certainly meant to import `java.util.List`, not `java.awt`. And do modernize to something like Spring MVC if at all possible.)

Comment: I am using Eclipse and in the debugger I have a session, but I cannot find anywhere in it a "name" parameter. When it's time to get the name from the session I get a null. If it were up to me, I would've used Spring

Comment: please post the code where you are setting the name session variable.

Comment: Added the code. The name is set in a different servlet, a log in page. From that page you get to another one, and from there you get to the first servlet I've posted

Comment: By default, sessions are maintained between requests by means of a cookie. Check the development tools in your browser to ensure 1. the JSESSIONID cookie is sent with each request and 2. it maintains the same value across your requests. Obvious question but you access all requests using base path `http://192.168.100.154:8080/GamePlatformCore/.....` ?

Answer (score -2):

You are using request scope attribute to get String value, use following code to get Session value:

```
<% String lobbyId = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(lobbyId); %>
```

Comment: I need to get the name from servlet1 to servlet2. The lobbyId parameter is not used in the second one. It is an old bit of code.